# SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name not showing the procedure content

Tags: mysql, linux, database, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

Hello I'm struggling with the Issue where i have to view the stored procedure content for that i have issue the command to get the name of the Procedure

```
mysql> SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS;
+-----+---------------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| Db  | Name                            | Type      | Definer   | Modified            | Created             | Security_type | Comment | character_set_client | collation_connection | Database Collation |
+-----+---------------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| vmp | ccontrol_table | PROCEDURE | user1@% | 2015-11-10 01:01:51 | 2015-11-10 01:01:51 | DEFINER       |         | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+-----+---------------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.27 sec)
```

It shows me the Procedure Exists with name **control_table**
To view the Procedure i have used **SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE control_table** it's display in this format not the **Content**

```
mysql> SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE control_table;
+---------------+----------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| Procedure     | sql_mode | Create Procedure | character_set_client | collation_connection | Database Collation |
+---------------+----------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| control_table |          | NULL             | utf8                 | utf8_general_ci      | latin1_swedish_ci  |
+---------------+----------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.28 sec)
```

I Have executed this Using MySQL Client and mySQL Client Workbench, not able to view the procedure

Comment: so what you want to do with this procedure are you trying to update it's content?

Comment: Yes Need to update the content

Comment: procedures can be found in routines tab of phpMyAdmin please check out there

Comment: There is no PHP Involved.

Comment: have u tried `SHOW PROCEDURE CODE control_table`

Comment: mysql> SHOW PROCEDURE CODE control_table
    -> ;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: show procedure already shows you the content of procedure if you have not entered anything in this procedure then it will not show you anything, you just need to use `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` and then enter the code for procedure and then check

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e83ad4/2

Answer (score 1):

Procedures are stored in information_schema.routines. The show create sees an entry in here for control_table but the routine_definition is empty - this suggests that someone has amended information_schema.routines. You can check the content of information_schema.routines with a simple select -

```
select routine_name,routine_definition 
from information_schema.ROUTINES
where routine_name = 'control_table'
```

== THIS is the Output=====

```
mysql> select routine_name,routine_definition 
    -> from information_schema.ROUTINES
    -> where routine_name = 'control_table'
    -> ;
+---------------------------------+--------------------+
| routine_name                    | routine_definition |
+---------------------------------+--------------------+
| control_table | NULL               |
+---------------------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.28 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need to update the body w/o standard SQL instructions (DROP/CREATE PROCEDURE) you can use the following instruction:

```
UPDATE  mysql.proc SET body='begin select 2 from dual; end' WHERE `name` = 'control_table';
```